# Foreach loop ajax

Tags: ajax, foreach

i am attempting to do a get via ajax and fill out some fields.

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url + '/' + product_id,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#name').val(data.name);
            $('#description').val(data.description);
            $('#btn-save').val("update");
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
```

So on button click this open ups the modal and fills out some fields with data from database.

As you can see I specify field names, which is just not an option, just wanted to see if I can get it to work.

But I'm not sure how to proceed now: I need to create a foreach loop and use keys as values, so something like:

```
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{$('$key').val($value);}
```

How should that look in ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax equivalent would be:

```
            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                $('#'+key).val(value);
            });
```